# Default constructor expression and lvalues

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, rvalue, copy-assignment

My C++ colleagues and I ran into a curious construct:

```cpp
struct A { int i; };
void foo(A const& a);

int main() {
  foo(A() = A{2}); // Legal
}
```

The `A() = A{2}` expression completely befuddled us as it appears to be assigning `A{2}` to a temporary, default-constructed object.  But see it in compiler explorer (https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/2LsfSk).  It appears to be a legal statement (supported by GCC 9 and Clang 9), as are the following statements:

```cpp
struct A { int i; };

int main() {
  A() = A{2};
  auto a = A() = A{3};
}
```

So it appears, then, that in some contexts `A()` is an lvalue.  Or is something else going on here?  Would appreciate some explanation and, preferably, a reference to the C++17 standard.

---

**Update**: @Brian found that this is a duplicate of [assigning to rvalue: why does this compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33784044/assigning-to-rvalue-why-does-this-compile).  But would really appreciate if someone could find the appropriate reference in the C++ standard.

Comment: @Brian Is it a duplicate?  `int() = 2;` is also assignment to an rvalue, but it is not allowed by the compiler.  So what makes user-defined types different?

Comment: The duplicate explains this. If the LHS is a class, then the assignment operation calls `operator=`. If the LHS is a non-class, then the built-in operator is used, which requires an lvalue.

Comment: @Brian, Fine but the duplicate doesn't specify the section of the language standard that's relevant...and that's what I requested.

Comment: All right. I reopened the question.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28598468/

Comment: Another dup: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35378090/9585016

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`A{}` is always an rvalue per [[expr.type.conv]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.type.conv)

> [1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.type.conv#1) **A *[simple-type-specifier](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.type.simple)*** or *[typename-specifier](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.res)* **followed** by a parenthesized optional *[expression-list](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.post#nt:expression-list)* or **by a *[braced-init-list](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init#nt:braced-init-list)*** (the initializer) constructs a value of the specified type given the initializer.
>   If the type is a placeholder for a deduced class type, it is replaced by the return type of the function selected by overload resolution for [class template deduction](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over.match.class.deduct) for the remainder of this subclause.
>   [2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.type.conv#2) If the initializer is a parenthesized single expression, the type conversion expression is equivalent to the corresponding [cast expression](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.cast).
>   Otherwise, if the type is *cv* `void` and the initializer is `()` or `{}` (after pack expansion, if any), the expression is a prvalue of the specified type that performs no initialization.
>   **Otherwise, the expression is a prvalue** of the specified type whose result object is [direct-initialized](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init#def:direct-initialization) with the initializer.
>   If the initializer is a parenthesized optional *[expression-list](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.post#nt:expression-list)*, the specified type shall not be an array type.

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

The reason these works is here is nothing in the standard to stop it from working.

For built in types like `int` there is [[expr.ass]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.ass#1)

> The assignment operator (=) and the compound assignment operators all group right-to-left. All require a modifiable lvalue as their left operand; their result is an lvalue referring to the left operand.

So this stops you from doing `int{} = 42;`.  This section doesn't apply to classes, though.  If we look in [[class.copy.assign]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.copy.assign) there is nothing that says that an lvalue is required, but the first paragraph does state

> A user-declared copy assignment operator X​::​operator= is a non-static non-template member function of class X with exactly one parameter of type X, X&, const X&, volatile X&, or const volatile X&

Which means

```
A{} = A{2};
```

is actually

```
A{}.operator=(A{2})
```

Which is legal to do on an rvalue class object since the default `operator =` for your class has no *ref-qualifier* to stop it from being called on rvalues.  If you add

```
A& operator=(const A& a) & { i = a.i; }
```

to `A` instead of using the default assignment operator then

```
A{} = A{2};
```

would no longer compile since the `operator=` will only work on lvalues now.

Comment: Thanks.  Close.  I think I just found it--8.2.1[basic.lval], paragraph 2.

Comment: @KyleKnoepfel Added that bit in so you have standard references for each bit.

Comment: @KyleKnoepfel [basic.lval] only speaks about properties of Zvalues, but it doesn't say which expressions are lvalues/xvalues/prvalues.